# Ports and Port forwarding

Tags: ip, http, dhcp, port, port-forwarding

In port forwarding all the ports (extensions of IP’s which altogether create ’the packet’) are associated with IP addresses. When configuring PCP (Port Control Protocol) via router settings- only the port of accesing device you want to open up to the Firewall is needed?

When you use port forwarding for redirecting port nr 80 (HTTP-webtraffic in case of own web server this one is in such case blocked) ,to do this you statically map the external IP address + port 80 to the Internal IP address of the web server + port 80. – **There are suggestions it works only with confirgured static IP, or can be DHCP allowed as well?**

Comment: "_the ports (extensions of IP’s which altogether create ’the packet’)_" That really is not true. Ports are the addresses for _some_ transport protocols, e.g. TCP and UDP, and they have nothing to do with an IP packet. IP has its own addressing (IPv4 or IPv6 addresses), and IP is unaware of what transport protocol or addressing is used in the payload of an IP packet. Routers route packets based on the destination IP address, and the router has no knowledge of the payload of an IP packet. You are confusing the NAPT variant of NAT with routing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and kind of you for clarifying, Ron. NAT works on level of IP's translation and port fowarding functions on port level. In order for port forwading to work there needs to be set up on the device a static IPv4, please? Not a dynamic, otherwise will not work and then to enter it on router as has been set up previousely? I mean if IPV4 is dynamic the port cannot be opened, as there are suggestions to configure it to static..@Ron Maupin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly Norka as you assume, to have the networking set up  proprely, you'll need to set a static internal IP address (ipv4) for your device.
DHCP can cause all the port forwarding rules to be in vain if you’re assigning them to devices with dynamic IP.
It's highly recommended to set up a Dynamic DNS service which will allow you to link your (changing) home IP address to a memorable address.
As long as you assign a static IP address to the target device and set up a dynamic DNS server for your home IP address you can access your network with easy.

Comment: Great John, thanks for reassuring me in the set up. You are a legend. @John

Comment: Any other queries would arise, I would be glad to assist you further (can continue via chat if you wish)  ;) @Norka